# Find the numbers that Anuj missed.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Anuj started writing some natural numbers starting from 1 and calculated the sum. Later he realized that he forgot to add two consecutive numbers and calculated the wrong sum as 2024. Find the numbers that Anuj missed.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: i dont know how to approach?

Comment: As a hint to get you started:  there is a simple closed formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i$.   Use that to find values of $n$ which are greater than $2024$, but close to it.  Should be easy to conclude from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that sum of n consecutive natural numbers is n(n+1)/2 and it is given to you that $\sum_{i=1}^n i$=$2024$ +$(k+(k+1))$ where k and k+1 are missed numbers.

Now $n(n+1)/2$=$2024$ +$(k+(k+1))$ or $n(n+1)$ = $4048$+$2(2k+1)$.

You just have to find product of two consecutive integers nearest(and greater) to $4048$ and it is $4160$. So you get that $2(2k+1)$=$4160$-$4048$=$112$.
I shall let you conclude.

Comment: Why does the product need to be the one nearest to $4048$?

Comment: It is the convenient way. I know that there can be many solutions and mine is just one of them

Answer (score -1):

Sum of 1 to 65, missed out 60 and 61.

How I got there? Basically some trial and error with the help of MATLAB.